# How to make a spinnable circle in css using ion-slides

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to create a circle which would spin in the direction its dragged. There are supposed to be elements on the border of the circle so the elements should spin. For example, these are the elements:

```html
 <ion-slides [options]="slideOpts">
      <ion-slide>
        <div style="background: black; height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <div style="background: red; height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <div style="background: yellow; height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Here is an image that I hope can make things clearer.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: border-radius, transform & animation are about what you need to start with.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ionicframework](https://ionicframework.com) Api [slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides) spinnable `event` isn't available. You can do using `CSS3` custom `animation`. You have to learn more about [CSS Animation](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/the-guide-to-css-animation-principles-and-examples/). Below is an example code.

```
<div class="proloader">
    <div class="loader">
    </div>
</div>

*,
*:after,
*:before{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.proloader{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #fff;
}
.proloader {
     align-items: center;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: center;
}
 .proloader .loader {
     animation: load5 1.1s infinite ease;
     border-radius: 50%;
     font-size: 25px;
     height: 10px;
     position: relative;
     text-indent: -9999em;
     transform: translateZ(0);
     width: 10px;
}
 @keyframes load5 {
     0%, 100% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #000, 25px -58px 0 0 #200, 45px -45px 0 0 #720000, 58px -24px 0 0 #a30000, 63px 0 0 0 #c00, 57px 24px 0 0 #f00, 44px 44px 0 0 #f33, 25px 57px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 0 63px 0 0 #ff7d7d, -24px 58px 0 0 #ff9797, -45px 45px 0 0 #ffacac, -58px 24px 0 0 #ffbdbd, -65px 0 0 0 #ffcaca, -58px -24px 0 0 #ffd5d5, -45px -45px 0 0 #fdd, -25px -58px 0 0 white;
    }
     6.25% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 white, 25px -58px 0 0 #000, 45px -45px 0 0 #200, 58px -24px 0 0 #720000, 63px 0 0 0 #a30000, 57px 24px 0 0 #c00, 44px 44px 0 0 #f00, 25px 57px 0 0 #f33, 0 63px 0 0 #ff5c5c, -24px 58px 0 0 #ff7d7d, -45px 45px 0 0 #ff9797, -58px 24px 0 0 #ffacac, -65px 0 0 0 #ffbdbd, -58px -24px 0 0 #ffcaca, -45px -45px 0 0 #ffd5d5, -25px -58px 0 0 #fdd;
    }
     12.5% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #fdd, 25px -58px 0 0 white, 45px -45px 0 0 #000, 58px -24px 0 0 #200, 63px 0 0 0 #720000, 57px 24px 0 0 #a30000, 44px 44px 0 0 #c00, 25px 57px 0 0 #f00, 0 63px 0 0 #f33, -24px 58px 0 0 #ff5c5c, -45px 45px 0 0 #ff7d7d, -58px 24px 0 0 #ff9797, -65px 0 0 0 #ffacac, -58px -24px 0 0 #ffbdbd, -45px -45px 0 0 #ffcaca, -25px -58px 0 0 #ffd5d5;
    }
     18.75% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 25px -58px 0 0 #fdd, 45px -45px 0 0 white, 58px -24px 0 0 #000, 63px 0 0 0 #200, 57px 24px 0 0 #720000, 44px 44px 0 0 #a30000, 25px 57px 0 0 #c00, 0 63px 0 0 #f00, -24px 58px 0 0 #f33, -45px 45px 0 0 #ff5c5c, -58px 24px 0 0 #ff7d7d, -65px 0 0 0 #ff9797, -58px -24px 0 0 #ffacac, -45px -45px 0 0 #ffbdbd, -25px -58px 0 0 #ffcaca;
    }
     25% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ffcaca, 25px -58px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 45px -45px 0 0 #fdd, 58px -24px 0 0 white, 63px 0 0 0 #000, 57px 24px 0 0 #200, 44px 44px 0 0 #720000, 25px 57px 0 0 #a30000, 0 63px 0 0 #c00, -24px 58px 0 0 #f00, -45px 45px 0 0 #f33, -58px 24px 0 0 #ff5c5c, -65px 0 0 0 #ff7d7d, -58px -24px 0 0 #ff9797, -45px -45px 0 0 #ffacac, -25px -58px 0 0 #ffbdbd;
    }
     31.25% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 25px -58px 0 0 #ffcaca, 45px -45px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 58px -24px 0 0 #fdd, 63px 0 0 0 white, 57px 24px 0 0 #000, 44px 44px 0 0 #200, 25px 57px 0 0 #720000, 0 63px 0 0 #a30000, -24px 58px 0 0 #c00, -45px 45px 0 0 #f00, -58px 24px 0 0 #f33, -65px 0 0 0 #ff5c5c, -58px -24px 0 0 #ff7d7d, -45px -45px 0 0 #ff9797, -25px -58px 0 0 #ffacac;
    }
     37.5% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ffacac, 25px -58px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 45px -45px 0 0 #ffcaca, 58px -24px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 63px 0 0 0 #fdd, 57px 24px 0 0 white, 44px 44px 0 0 #000, 25px 57px 0 0 #200, 0 63px 0 0 #720000, -24px 58px 0 0 #a30000, -45px 45px 0 0 #c00, -58px 24px 0 0 #f00, -65px 0 0 0 #f33, -58px -24px 0 0 #ff5c5c, -45px -45px 0 0 #ff7d7d, -25px -58px 0 0 #ff9797;
    }
     43.75% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ff9797, 25px -58px 0 0 #ffacac, 45px -45px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 58px -24px 0 0 #ffcaca, 63px 0 0 0 #ffd5d5, 57px 24px 0 0 #fdd, 44px 44px 0 0 white, 25px 57px 0 0 #000, 0 63px 0 0 #200, -24px 58px 0 0 #720000, -45px 45px 0 0 #a30000, -58px 24px 0 0 #c00, -65px 0 0 0 #f00, -58px -24px 0 0 #f33, -45px -45px 0 0 #ff5c5c, -25px -58px 0 0 #ff7d7d;
    }
     50% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 25px -58px 0 0 #ff9797, 45px -45px 0 0 #ffacac, 58px -24px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 63px 0 0 0 #ffcaca, 57px 24px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 44px 44px 0 0 #fdd, 25px 57px 0 0 white, 0 63px 0 0 #000, -24px 58px 0 0 #200, -45px 45px 0 0 #720000, -58px 24px 0 0 #a30000, -65px 0 0 0 #c00, -58px -24px 0 0 #f00, -45px -45px 0 0 #f33, -25px -58px 0 0 #ff5c5c;
    }
     56.25% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 25px -58px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 45px -45px 0 0 #ff9797, 58px -24px 0 0 #ffacac, 63px 0 0 0 #ffbdbd, 57px 24px 0 0 #ffcaca, 44px 44px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 25px 57px 0 0 #fdd, 0 63px 0 0 white, -24px 58px 0 0 #000, -45px 45px 0 0 #200, -58px 24px 0 0 #720000, -65px 0 0 0 #a30000, -58px -24px 0 0 #c00, -45px -45px 0 0 #f00, -25px -58px 0 0 #f33;
    }
     62.5% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #f33, 25px -58px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 45px -45px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 58px -24px 0 0 #ff9797, 63px 0 0 0 #ffacac, 57px 24px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 44px 44px 0 0 #ffcaca, 25px 57px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 0 63px 0 0 #fdd, -24px 58px 0 0 white, -45px 45px 0 0 #000, -58px 24px 0 0 #200, -65px 0 0 0 #720000, -58px -24px 0 0 #a30000, -45px -45px 0 0 #c00, -25px -58px 0 0 #f00;
    }
     68.75% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #f00, 25px -58px 0 0 #f33, 45px -45px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 58px -24px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 63px 0 0 0 #ff9797, 57px 24px 0 0 #ffacac, 44px 44px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 25px 57px 0 0 #ffcaca, 0 63px 0 0 #ffd5d5, -24px 58px 0 0 #fdd, -45px 45px 0 0 white, -58px 24px 0 0 #000, -65px 0 0 0 #200, -58px -24px 0 0 #720000, -45px -45px 0 0 #a30000, -25px -58px 0 0 #c00;
    }
     75% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #c00, 25px -58px 0 0 #f00, 45px -45px 0 0 #f33, 58px -24px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 63px 0 0 0 #ff7d7d, 57px 24px 0 0 #ff9797, 44px 44px 0 0 #ffacac, 25px 57px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 0 63px 0 0 #ffcaca, -24px 58px 0 0 #ffd5d5, -45px 45px 0 0 #fdd, -58px 24px 0 0 white, -65px 0 0 0 #000, -58px -24px 0 0 #200, -45px -45px 0 0 #720000, -25px -58px 0 0 #a30000;
    }
     81.25% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #a30000, 25px -58px 0 0 #c00, 45px -45px 0 0 #f00, 58px -24px 0 0 #f33, 63px 0 0 0 #ff5c5c, 57px 24px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 44px 44px 0 0 #ff9797, 25px 57px 0 0 #ffacac, 0 63px 0 0 #ffbdbd, -24px 58px 0 0 #ffcaca, -45px 45px 0 0 #ffd5d5, -58px 24px 0 0 #fdd, -65px 0 0 0 white, -58px -24px 0 0 #000, -45px -45px 0 0 #200, -25px -58px 0 0 #720000;
    }
     87.5% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #720000, 25px -58px 0 0 #a30000, 45px -45px 0 0 #c00, 58px -24px 0 0 #f00, 63px 0 0 0 #f33, 57px 24px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 44px 44px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 25px 57px 0 0 #ff9797, 0 63px 0 0 #ffacac, -24px 58px 0 0 #ffbdbd, -45px 45px 0 0 #ffcaca, -58px 24px 0 0 #ffd5d5, -65px 0 0 0 #fdd, -58px -24px 0 0 white, -45px -45px 0 0 #000, -25px -58px 0 0 #200;
    }
     93.75% {
         box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #200, 25px -58px 0 0 #720000, 45px -45px 0 0 #a30000, 58px -24px 0 0 #c00, 63px 0 0 0 #f00, 57px 24px 0 0 #f33, 44px 44px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 25px 57px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 0 63px 0 0 #ff9797, -24px 58px 0 0 #ffacac, -45px 45px 0 0 #ffbdbd, -58px 24px 0 0 #ffcaca, -65px 0 0 0 #ffd5d5, -58px -24px 0 0 #fdd, -45px -45px 0 0 white, -25px -58px 0 0 #000;
    }
}
```

Snippet is below.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.proloader{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #fff;
}
.proloader {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
 .proloader .loader {
  animation: load5 1.1s infinite ease;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  width: 10px;
}
 @keyframes load5 {
  0%, 100% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #000, 25px -58px 0 0 #200, 45px -45px 0 0 #720000, 58px -24px 0 0 #a30000, 63px 0 0 0 #c00, 57px 24px 0 0 #f00, 44px 44px 0 0 #f33, 25px 57px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 0 63px 0 0 #ff7d7d, -24px 58px 0 0 #ff9797, -45px 45px 0 0 #ffacac, -58px 24px 0 0 #ffbdbd, -65px 0 0 0 #ffcaca, -58px -24px 0 0 #ffd5d5, -45px -45px 0 0 #fdd, -25px -58px 0 0 white;
 }
  6.25% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 white, 25px -58px 0 0 #000, 45px -45px 0 0 #200, 58px -24px 0 0 #720000, 63px 0 0 0 #a30000, 57px 24px 0 0 #c00, 44px 44px 0 0 #f00, 25px 57px 0 0 #f33, 0 63px 0 0 #ff5c5c, -24px 58px 0 0 #ff7d7d, -45px 45px 0 0 #ff9797, -58px 24px 0 0 #ffacac, -65px 0 0 0 #ffbdbd, -58px -24px 0 0 #ffcaca, -45px -45px 0 0 #ffd5d5, -25px -58px 0 0 #fdd;
 }
  12.5% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #fdd, 25px -58px 0 0 white, 45px -45px 0 0 #000, 58px -24px 0 0 #200, 63px 0 0 0 #720000, 57px 24px 0 0 #a30000, 44px 44px 0 0 #c00, 25px 57px 0 0 #f00, 0 63px 0 0 #f33, -24px 58px 0 0 #ff5c5c, -45px 45px 0 0 #ff7d7d, -58px 24px 0 0 #ff9797, -65px 0 0 0 #ffacac, -58px -24px 0 0 #ffbdbd, -45px -45px 0 0 #ffcaca, -25px -58px 0 0 #ffd5d5;
 }
  18.75% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 25px -58px 0 0 #fdd, 45px -45px 0 0 white, 58px -24px 0 0 #000, 63px 0 0 0 #200, 57px 24px 0 0 #720000, 44px 44px 0 0 #a30000, 25px 57px 0 0 #c00, 0 63px 0 0 #f00, -24px 58px 0 0 #f33, -45px 45px 0 0 #ff5c5c, -58px 24px 0 0 #ff7d7d, -65px 0 0 0 #ff9797, -58px -24px 0 0 #ffacac, -45px -45px 0 0 #ffbdbd, -25px -58px 0 0 #ffcaca;
 }
  25% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ffcaca, 25px -58px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 45px -45px 0 0 #fdd, 58px -24px 0 0 white, 63px 0 0 0 #000, 57px 24px 0 0 #200, 44px 44px 0 0 #720000, 25px 57px 0 0 #a30000, 0 63px 0 0 #c00, -24px 58px 0 0 #f00, -45px 45px 0 0 #f33, -58px 24px 0 0 #ff5c5c, -65px 0 0 0 #ff7d7d, -58px -24px 0 0 #ff9797, -45px -45px 0 0 #ffacac, -25px -58px 0 0 #ffbdbd;
 }
  31.25% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 25px -58px 0 0 #ffcaca, 45px -45px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 58px -24px 0 0 #fdd, 63px 0 0 0 white, 57px 24px 0 0 #000, 44px 44px 0 0 #200, 25px 57px 0 0 #720000, 0 63px 0 0 #a30000, -24px 58px 0 0 #c00, -45px 45px 0 0 #f00, -58px 24px 0 0 #f33, -65px 0 0 0 #ff5c5c, -58px -24px 0 0 #ff7d7d, -45px -45px 0 0 #ff9797, -25px -58px 0 0 #ffacac;
 }
  37.5% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ffacac, 25px -58px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 45px -45px 0 0 #ffcaca, 58px -24px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 63px 0 0 0 #fdd, 57px 24px 0 0 white, 44px 44px 0 0 #000, 25px 57px 0 0 #200, 0 63px 0 0 #720000, -24px 58px 0 0 #a30000, -45px 45px 0 0 #c00, -58px 24px 0 0 #f00, -65px 0 0 0 #f33, -58px -24px 0 0 #ff5c5c, -45px -45px 0 0 #ff7d7d, -25px -58px 0 0 #ff9797;
 }
  43.75% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ff9797, 25px -58px 0 0 #ffacac, 45px -45px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 58px -24px 0 0 #ffcaca, 63px 0 0 0 #ffd5d5, 57px 24px 0 0 #fdd, 44px 44px 0 0 white, 25px 57px 0 0 #000, 0 63px 0 0 #200, -24px 58px 0 0 #720000, -45px 45px 0 0 #a30000, -58px 24px 0 0 #c00, -65px 0 0 0 #f00, -58px -24px 0 0 #f33, -45px -45px 0 0 #ff5c5c, -25px -58px 0 0 #ff7d7d;
 }
  50% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 25px -58px 0 0 #ff9797, 45px -45px 0 0 #ffacac, 58px -24px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 63px 0 0 0 #ffcaca, 57px 24px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 44px 44px 0 0 #fdd, 25px 57px 0 0 white, 0 63px 0 0 #000, -24px 58px 0 0 #200, -45px 45px 0 0 #720000, -58px 24px 0 0 #a30000, -65px 0 0 0 #c00, -58px -24px 0 0 #f00, -45px -45px 0 0 #f33, -25px -58px 0 0 #ff5c5c;
 }
  56.25% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 25px -58px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 45px -45px 0 0 #ff9797, 58px -24px 0 0 #ffacac, 63px 0 0 0 #ffbdbd, 57px 24px 0 0 #ffcaca, 44px 44px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 25px 57px 0 0 #fdd, 0 63px 0 0 white, -24px 58px 0 0 #000, -45px 45px 0 0 #200, -58px 24px 0 0 #720000, -65px 0 0 0 #a30000, -58px -24px 0 0 #c00, -45px -45px 0 0 #f00, -25px -58px 0 0 #f33;
 }
  62.5% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #f33, 25px -58px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 45px -45px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 58px -24px 0 0 #ff9797, 63px 0 0 0 #ffacac, 57px 24px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 44px 44px 0 0 #ffcaca, 25px 57px 0 0 #ffd5d5, 0 63px 0 0 #fdd, -24px 58px 0 0 white, -45px 45px 0 0 #000, -58px 24px 0 0 #200, -65px 0 0 0 #720000, -58px -24px 0 0 #a30000, -45px -45px 0 0 #c00, -25px -58px 0 0 #f00;
 }
  68.75% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #f00, 25px -58px 0 0 #f33, 45px -45px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 58px -24px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 63px 0 0 0 #ff9797, 57px 24px 0 0 #ffacac, 44px 44px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 25px 57px 0 0 #ffcaca, 0 63px 0 0 #ffd5d5, -24px 58px 0 0 #fdd, -45px 45px 0 0 white, -58px 24px 0 0 #000, -65px 0 0 0 #200, -58px -24px 0 0 #720000, -45px -45px 0 0 #a30000, -25px -58px 0 0 #c00;
 }
  75% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #c00, 25px -58px 0 0 #f00, 45px -45px 0 0 #f33, 58px -24px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 63px 0 0 0 #ff7d7d, 57px 24px 0 0 #ff9797, 44px 44px 0 0 #ffacac, 25px 57px 0 0 #ffbdbd, 0 63px 0 0 #ffcaca, -24px 58px 0 0 #ffd5d5, -45px 45px 0 0 #fdd, -58px 24px 0 0 white, -65px 0 0 0 #000, -58px -24px 0 0 #200, -45px -45px 0 0 #720000, -25px -58px 0 0 #a30000;
 }
  81.25% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #a30000, 25px -58px 0 0 #c00, 45px -45px 0 0 #f00, 58px -24px 0 0 #f33, 63px 0 0 0 #ff5c5c, 57px 24px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 44px 44px 0 0 #ff9797, 25px 57px 0 0 #ffacac, 0 63px 0 0 #ffbdbd, -24px 58px 0 0 #ffcaca, -45px 45px 0 0 #ffd5d5, -58px 24px 0 0 #fdd, -65px 0 0 0 white, -58px -24px 0 0 #000, -45px -45px 0 0 #200, -25px -58px 0 0 #720000;
 }
  87.5% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #720000, 25px -58px 0 0 #a30000, 45px -45px 0 0 #c00, 58px -24px 0 0 #f00, 63px 0 0 0 #f33, 57px 24px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 44px 44px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 25px 57px 0 0 #ff9797, 0 63px 0 0 #ffacac, -24px 58px 0 0 #ffbdbd, -45px 45px 0 0 #ffcaca, -58px 24px 0 0 #ffd5d5, -65px 0 0 0 #fdd, -58px -24px 0 0 white, -45px -45px 0 0 #000, -25px -58px 0 0 #200;
 }
  93.75% {
   box-shadow: 0 -65px 0 0 #200, 25px -58px 0 0 #720000, 45px -45px 0 0 #a30000, 58px -24px 0 0 #c00, 63px 0 0 0 #f00, 57px 24px 0 0 #f33, 44px 44px 0 0 #ff5c5c, 25px 57px 0 0 #ff7d7d, 0 63px 0 0 #ff9797, -24px 58px 0 0 #ffacac, -45px 45px 0 0 #ffbdbd, -58px 24px 0 0 #ffcaca, -65px 0 0 0 #ffd5d5, -58px -24px 0 0 #fdd, -45px -45px 0 0 white, -25px -58px 0 0 #000;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="proloader">
 <div class="loader">
 </div>
</div>
```

Go to [CSS Animation Library](https://css-tricks.com/css-animation-libraries/) Or [Animista](https://animista.net).

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for! I need the circle to spin only when the user drags it.